# vertical centering in tabular using array and booktabs

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, arrays, booktabs

In the following school timetable for my 4 kids I am trying to use `array` and the `m{}` command (vertical align middle) to get the word *Peter* to be vertically aligned in its cell, (at the `cmidrule`), because this is the vertical centre.  Similarly, the word *Sonya* should be vertically aligned within her row.  The horizontal rules are provided by `booktabs`.  My problem is that the children names are not being vertically centred.

The effect I want is like this [image]

As a follow-up question, if I (I know it looks bad, I'm just asking hypothetically) wanted the names in the first column to have both centred vertical alignment (`m{}`) and centred horizontal alignment (`c`), what is the best method?  Should I use `hfill` inside a `m{}` column?

I have read similar questions such as  [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66564/vertical-alignment-using-multirow-and-booktabs) but I'm not sure they're identical because I'm not using `multirow` or `multicol`. Also, the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6355/problem-with-table-vertical-alignment?rq=1) requires a manual height estimate, whereas I am looking for something automatic.

The almost-MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newlength{\cwidth}
\setlength{\cwidth}{1.4in}
\begin{document}

\section{School Timetable}

\begin{tabular}{m{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}@{}} \toprule

&\textbf{Mon}&\textbf{Tues}&\textbf{Wed}&\textbf{Thurs}&\textbf{Fri}\\ \midrule
 \textbf{Peter}&
Creative Arts\newline HSIE\newline Science &
English\newline Maths\newline Science\newline PDHPE---no sports&
Maths\newline TAS\newline Sport&
TAS\newline English\newline Science\newline Maths&
HSIE\newline Creative Arts\newline English \\ 
 \cmidrule(r){2-6}  
&English\newline HSIE\newline Science\newline PDHPE---no sports&
Science\newline Creative Arts\newline PDHPE---sports\newline English&
Maths\newline TAS\newline Sport&
PDHPE---sports\newline Maths\newline Creative Arts\newline TAS&
Science\newline English\newline Maths\newline HSIE\\ \midrule

\textbf{Sonya}&
&
&
&
Sport uniform\newline Library\newline Homework collected&
Homework issued \\ \midrule

\textbf{Michael}&
Sport Uniform&
Library&
&
Homework collected&
Homework issued\\ \midrule

\textbf{Andrew}&
Sport Uniform&
Library&
&
Homework collected&
Homework issued\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `makecell` and `multirow`, you have the first column horizontally centred by default (but it may be changed). The `makecell` package allows for a common formatting and linebreaks in table cells, with the ``` thead,\makecell, \multirowthead,``multirowcell ``` commands:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.2in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, makecell, multirow}
\newlength{\cwidth}
\setlength{\cwidth}{1.4in}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{School Timetable}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{m{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}@{}} \toprule
                    & \textbf{Mon} & \textbf{Tues} & \textbf{Wed} & \textbf{Thurs} & \textbf{Fri} \\%
    \midrule
    \multirowthead{8}[-\aboverulesep]{\textbf{Peter}}%
    & Creative Arts\newline HSIE\newline Science %
    & English\newline Maths\newline Science\newline PDHPE---no sports %
    & Maths\newline TAS\newline Sport %
    & TAS\newline English\newline Science\newline Maths%
    & HSIE\newline Creative Arts\newline English \\ %
    \cmidrule(r){2-6}
    & English\newline HSIE\newline Science\newline PDHPE---no sports%
    & Science\newline Creative Arts\newline PDHPE---sports\newline English%
    & Maths\newline TAS\newline Sport& PDHPE---sports\newline Maths\newline Creative Arts\newline TAS %
    & Science\newline English\newline Maths\newline HSIE \\%
    \midrule
    \multirowthead{3}{Sonya}&&&&%
    Sport uniform\newline Library\newline Homework collected & Homework issued \\%
    \midrule
    \thead{Michael} & Sport Uniform & Library & & Homework collected & Homework issued \\%
    \midrule
    \thead{Andrew} & Sport Uniform&
    Library&
    &
    Homework collected & Homework issued\\%
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the `multirow` package :

```
\multirow{8}[4]*{\textbf{Peter}}&
```

the code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newlength{\cwidth}
\setlength{\cwidth}{1.4in}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\section{School Timetable}

\begin{tabular}{m{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}p{\cwidth}@{}} \toprule

&\textbf{Mon}&\textbf{Tues}&\textbf{Wed}&\textbf{Thurs}&\textbf{Fri}\\ \midrule
  \multirow{8}[4]*{\textbf{Peter}}&
Creative Arts\newline HSIE\newline Science &
English\newline Maths\newline Science\newline PDHPE---no sports&
Maths\newline TAS\newline Sport&
TAS\newline English\newline Science\newline Maths&
HSIE\newline Creative Arts\newline English \\ 
 \cmidrule(r){2-6}  
&English\newline HSIE\newline Science\newline PDHPE---no sports&
Science\newline Creative Arts\newline PDHPE---sports\newline English&
Maths\newline TAS\newline Sport&
PDHPE---sports\newline Maths\newline Creative Arts\newline TAS&
Science\newline English\newline Maths\newline HSIE\\ \midrule

  \multirow{3}*{\textbf{Sonya}}&
&
&
&
Sport uniform\newline Library\newline Homework collected&
Homework issued \\ \midrule

\textbf{Michael}&
Sport Uniform&
Library&
&
Homework collected&
Homework issued\\ \midrule

\textbf{Andrew}&
Sport Uniform&
Library&
&
Homework collected&
Homework issued\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]